# PHP Remove black bar from image

Tags: php, image

I have a script that crops and rotates an image.

But i end up with a black bar in my image:

http://prntscr.com/r9l1w5   (screenshot)

I found a script on the internet, that is able to remove black bars on images. But i am unable to make it work together on 1 page.

(view-image.php) My script:

```
    <?php
$filenamegetter = $_GET['imgid'];
$degree = 0;
// File and rotation
$filename = 'img/' . $filenamegetter . '';
$degrees = $degree;
  $percent = 0.30;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');


// Get new sizes

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

if ($width > "1000") {
  $newwidth = $width * $percent;
  $newheight = $height * $percent;

} else {
  $newwidth = $width;
  $newheight = $height;
}



// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $rotate, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);



imagejpeg($thumb);


// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($thumb);
?>
```

The anti black bar script i wish it works together with:

```
<?php

$image_path = "image.jpg";

$jpg = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
$black = array("red" => 0, "green" => 0, "blue" => 0, "alpha" => 0);

$removeLeft = 0;
for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($jpg); $x++) {
    for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($jpg); $y++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeLeft += 1;
}

$removeRight = 0;
for($x = imagesx($jpg)-1; $x > 0; $x--) {
    for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($jpg); $y++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeRight += 1;
}

$removeTop = 0;
for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($jpg); $y++) {
    for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($jpg); $x++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeTop += 1;
}

$removeBottom = 0;
for($y = imagesy($jpg)-1; $y > 0; $y--) {
    for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($jpg); $x++) {
        if(imagecolorsforindex($jpg, imagecolorat($jpg, $x, $y)) != $black){
            break 2;
        }
    }
    $removeBottom += 1;
}

$cropped = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($jpg) - ($removeLeft + $removeRight), imagesy($jpg) - ($removeTop + $removeBottom));
imagecopy($cropped, $jpg, 0, 0, $removeLeft, $removeTop, imagesx($cropped), imagesy($cropped));

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($cropped); //change to `imagejpeg($cropped, $image_path);` to save
imagedestroy($cropped);
imagedestroy($jpg);
```

I'd like to know how i can implent the anti black bar script in my script. I tried multiple ways but i end up with a empty page.

Comment: I think that black border appear as the image had a different size before. You are cropping and rotating the image inside the old frame. If you draw it in a new frame you wouldn't have that effect

Comment: How can I draw my image in a new frame?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having problems with `imagecopyresampled` or `imagerotate` with black bars on background, I have found a code example here:

There are a lot of factors but for me the problem was the new size after rotating the image.

https://qna.habr.com/q/646622#answer_1417035

```
        // get image sizes (X,Y)
        $wx = imagesx($imageW);
        $wy = imagesy($imageW);

        // create a new image from the sizes on transparent canvas
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($wx, $wy);

        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        $rotate = imagerotate($imageW, 280, $transparent);
        imagealphablending($rotate, true);
        imagesavealpha($rotate, true);

        // get the newest image X and Y
        $ix = imagesx($rotate);
        $iy = imagesy($rotate);

        //copy the image to the canvas
        imagecopyresampled($destImg, $rotate, 940, 2050, 0, 0, $ix, $iy, $ix, $iy);
```